# « A voté » ou « à voter » ?

Tags: orthographe, locutions, politique

Pour parler un peu de l'actualité française, comment écrire les paroles qu'ont les présidents de scrutin à chaque fois qu'un électeur dépose une enveloppe dans l'urne ?

Je n'ai jamais eu l'ombre d'un doute sur le fait que l'on écrive *a voté*, surtout qu'un assesseur fait précéder cette mention du nom de l'électeur :
  — M. X... 
  — ... a voté !

Cependant certains soutiennent l'autre orthographe. On pourrait rapprocher le *à voter* de *à suivre* ou *à paraitre*. Mais l'interprétation n'est alors pas très claire pour moi.

Quelqu'un a-t-il une opinion, ou mieux encore, une référence fiable à proposer ?

Answer (score 14):

L'expression « a voté » ne se trouve à ma connaissance dans aucun texte réglementaire. On pourra s'en convaincre en lisant le [code électoral](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/telecharger_pdf.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070239), ou les [instructions du ministère de l'intérieur](http://www.interieur.gouv.fr/sections/a_votre_service/elections/comment_voter/bureau-vote) (qui résument les articles ayant trait au déroulement du scrutin et les circulaires afférentes). (Le code électoral ne couvre pas les élections présidentielles ni les référendums, toutefois les procédures sont identiques.)

L'expression « a voté » est prononcée une fois que l'électeur a mis son bulletin dans l'urne. C'est donc bien un passé ; il s'agit de dire que *M. X a voté* (M. X vient de voter). Le temps qui convient ici en français est bien le participe passé. On note que c'est bien le fait de mettre le bulletin dans l'urne qui constitute l'acte de *voter*. Les opérations de vote dans leur ensemble constituent le *scrutin*. Le *dépouillement* (ouverture des enveloppes et comptage des résultats) s'effectue une fois le scrutin clos, et en particulier après que tous les votes ont eu lieu.

*À voter* serait une simple faute d'orthographe. Il n'y a aucun rapprochement possible avec *à suivre* ou *à paraître* qui parlent d'actions futures et hypothétiques.

Comment: Oui, je suis d'accord avec toi, mais ce ne serait pas la première fois que la langue française ait une orthographe contre-intuitive. Connais-tu un dictionnaire dans lequel cette locution est répertoriée ?

Comment: A moins qu'il s'agisse d'un particularisme local d'un parti qui prêche pour une énième réforme de l’orthographe, seul le contexte "Untel s’apprête *à voter* pour tel candidat" est en usage dans l'hexagone.

Comment: Que veux-tu dire ?

Comment: @cl-r Non, justement, l'expression est utilisée après le vote (une fois l'enveloppe dans l'urne), pas avant. Ce ne peut donc pas être un raccourci pour « s'apprête à voter », c'est forcément un passé.

Comment: @cl-r Il s'apprête *à voter* lorsqu'il répond aux instituts de sondage sur les intentions de vote. Mais le contexte ici est qu'il *a voté* quand son bulletin tombe dans l'urne.

Comment: @Lierre Pour http://olonnesurmer.fr/?lang=fr&keyRubrique=lexique-du-bureau-de-vote l'expression consacrée est **"a voté!"** ; dans http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proc%C3%A9dures_%C3%A9lectorales_fran%C3%A7aises ".. reçoit la signature de l'électeur après qu'il **a voté.** " - Dans quelle localité, dans quel milieu social avez-vous entendu cette expression?

Comment: @cl-r — Simplement un ami qui me soutiens le contraire, et je n'ai que le bon sens à lui opposer, ce qui, en matière de langue française, est un peu léger.

Comment: @Lierre .. et que pense-t-il des réponses apportées? Normalement l'usage l'emporte (surtout lorsqu'il est soutenu par la logique grammaticale) lorsque qu'aucune règle écrite ne le contredit (enfin c'est avec ces principes que je vis depuis longtemps déjà). Peut-être une affirmation de 1er avril?

Comment: @cl-r — Disons que ça manque d'une référence dans un dictionnaire... Mais après tout, la charge de la preuve revient à celui qui va à l'encontre de la logique !

Answer (score -5):

Une fois le vote effectué, on appelle "à voter".

Comment: Pourquoi diantre appellerait-on « à voter » après que le vote eut été effectué ?

Comment: @Tom92 Tu peux effacer ta réponse et récupérer des points

Comment: @cl-r: Quels points peut-il récupérer puisqu'il a "1" de réputation ?

Comment: @Zistoloen Au moins un badge "peer pressure"

Comment: @cl-r: Ok pour un petit badge.